# How do I edit a HTML element from a controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to make it so when I click on a button, a method is called and some text on the page is updated. (The button runs some methods and updates a Semantic UI progress bar with how many methods it's done.)

How would I do this?

I'm using Razor, ASP.NET Core MVC, and ASP.NET Core 5.

Comment: Look into ajax calls, and please provide what you've tried already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Basically it's not a good idea to interact with UI elements in the controller. Doing that you ruin the whole idea behind the MVC pattern a part of which is the Controller.(The controller should know nothing of the view.)
- Moreover each execution of a method in the controller represents executing a synchronous request to the server which results in refreshing the page in your browser. Imagine the page refreshes every time the progress bar needs to update. I guess you don't want this behavior. For updating a status bar in the way I think you want it you need to have asynchronous calls of those methods in your view.
- If you have to change the UI depending on methods execution status I would suggest using AJAX to make async calls to your methods in the controller and when a response from a finished method comes you update the progress bar.
  Hope now you have a better overview. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

So a possible solution would be:

Click listener in JS , which will send AJAX request to the controller. The controller function should return Non-relational data(preferably JSON). This data that was returned should be catched in the AJAX success function and in this success function you define you HTML change.